# JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container

Tags: jsf-2, el, web.xml, websphere-8

i am using **javax.faces-2.0.10.jar** on **websphere 8.5** and i am using **jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar** and in my web.xml i have the following configuration for el:

```
<context-param>     
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
  <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

in the logs i can see that jsf was initialized successfully but i see the following error too:

```
JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.
```

the classloader is set to parent last, and i can open jsp and xhtml pages with no errors, but i keep getting the above error in logs, any ideas why ?

Comment: It's a notice, not an error. But anyway, I've got this message too with Tomcat 7 on Mojarra JSF 2.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Way of creation of this error is described [here](http://my-java-planet.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-manage-with-info-jsf1027-null.html).

To resolve it you could try:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name> com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

as

> com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP
>   Specifies to load the JSF runtime when the application server starts up. If this parameter is set to false or removed, JSF runtime is loaded and initialized when the first JSF request is processed. This might disable custom JSF extensions such as factories defined in the project.

[WAS docs](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rweb_jsfengine.html)

You could try also to use your **jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar** as a shared library.